# How to center a footer within existing style

Tags: latex-misc

I need to center the headers and footers using `isov2`. For the header, I succeeded in adding `\hfill`s around the header text. But the footer is not that easily customizable.  I need the Copyright notice first and below the page number both centered. Here is what I tried by redefining the footer command (for the moment I just added the text `d1` to see what is happening. But it only works for a single page). How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass[final,copyright]{isov2}
\renewcommand{\copyrightname}{MISO/MIEC}
\yearofedition{2024}
\languageofedition{(en)}


\ifpdf
  \pdfoutput=1
  \usepackage[plainpages=false,
              pdfpagelabels,
              bookmarksnumbered,
              hyperindex=true
             ]{hyperref}
\fi

\makeindex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % add more levels to table of contents



\def\mywarning{draft-version\ }
\standard{\hfill\mywarning \copyrightname\ Text1--99:2099 (en)\hfill}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ps@headings}{%  my futile attempt
    \def\@oddhead{\bfseries\extrahead\hfil\@runninghead}%
    \def\@evenhead{\bfseries\@runninghead\hfil\extrahead}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\copyrighthead d1-even\hfil\thepage}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\thepage\hfil d1-odd\copyrighthead}}
\makeatother

\begin{cover}
Replace by real coverpage
\clearpage
\end{cover}

\begin{foreword}
\tocskip{\tocentryskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{clause}{\forewordname}
A terse foreword.
\newpage
And the final page.
\end{foreword}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code redefines the page styles to center the copyright and page number as asked. I don't know if said document complies with the ISO standard.

(Add `\pagestyle{headings}` after `\begin{document}`)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[final,copyright]{isov2}
\renewcommand{\copyrightname}{MISO/MIEC}
\yearofedition{2024}
\languageofedition{(en)}


\ifpdf
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[plainpages=false,
pdfpagelabels,
bookmarksnumbered,
hyperindex=true
]{hyperref}
\fi

\makeindex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % add more levels to table of contents

%**************************************************************
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ps@headings}{%
    \def\@oddhead{\bfseries\extrahead\hfil\@runninghead}%
    \def\@evenhead{\bfseries\@runninghead\hfil\extrahead}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\copyrighthead\linebreak\thepage}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \def\@evenfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\copyrighthead\linebreak\thepage}}}

\renewcommand{\ps@startpage}{%
    \def\@oddhead{\bfseries\extrahead\hfil\@runninghead}%
    \def\@evenhead{\bfseries\@runninghead\hfil\extrahead}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage\hfil}}


\def\ps@isotitlehead{%
    \def\@oddhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\rectoisotitlehead}}%
    \def\@evenhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\versoisotitlehead}}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering \copyrighthead\linebreak\thepage}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \def\@evenfoot{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering \copyrighthead\linebreak\thepage}}}

\makeatother        
%**************************************************************

\def\mywarning{draft-version\ }
\standard{\hfill\mywarning \copyrightname\ Text1--99:2099 (en)\hfill}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY to add dummy text <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{headings} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \begin{cover}
        Replace by real coverpage
        \clearpage
    \end{cover}
    
    \begin{foreword}
        \tocskip{\tocentryskip}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{clause}{\forewordname}
        A terse foreword.
        \newpage
        And the final page.
    \end{foreword}

\begin{introduction}
     Introduction\newpage
     some text
\end{introduction}


\title{}{Main Title}{complement}
\clearpage

\kant[1-5]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: So great! As for compliance, there are new rulez ....